# python- ERROR:snscrape.base:Error retrieving

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

Up until this morning I successfully used snscrape to scrape twitter tweets via python. The code looks like this:

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
import pandas as pd

# Setting variables to be used below
maxTweets = 10000
# Creating list to append tweet data to
tweets_list2 = []
# Using TwitterSearchScraper to scrape data and append tweets to list
for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('good since:2021-03-21 until:2022-03-20 lang:fa').get_items()):
    if i>maxTweets:
        break
    tweets_list2.append([tweet.date, tweet.id, tweet.content, tweet.username,tweet.lang,tweet.links,tweet.media])
# Creating a dataframe from the tweets list above
tweets_df2 = pd.DataFrame(tweets_list2, columns=['Datetime', 'Tweet Id','language','links','media', 'Username', 'Text'])
tweets_df2.to_csv("hamrah anten_2 1401.csv", index = False)
```

But this morning without any changes I got the error:

```
ERROR:snscrape.base:Error retrieving https://api.twitter.com/2/search/.....
CRITICAL:snscrape.base:4 requests to https://api.twitter.com/2/search/.....
CRITICAL:snscrape.base:Errors: blocked (403), blocked (403), blocked (403), blocked (403)
```

What can these errors be?
How to fix them?